# Variance of $y_i$ if $\sum_{i=1}^{10} {y_i} = 100$ ? Also find $\operatorname{cov}(y_i, y_j)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_{10})$, be a random vector with integer coordinates, uniformly distributed over the set $$\left\{(y_1,\dots,y_n)\;\middle|\,\, \sum_{i=1}^{10}y_i=100,y_i\in \mathbb Z,y_i\ge 0\right\}.$$ What are $\operatorname{var}(Y_i)$ and $\operatorname{cov}(Y_i, Y_j), i \neq j$?

I tried to solve this problem by finding the distribution of each $y_i$s. 
In fact, $f_{Y_i}(y) = \frac{{108-y} \choose 8}{109 \choose 9} $.

It is clear that $E(Y_i) = 10 \forall i$ as the distributions are identical, so $ \sum_{i=1}^{10} E(Y_i) = 100  \Rightarrow E(Y_i) = 10 \forall i$.

But how do i evaluate $$\sum_{y=0}^{100} y^2 \frac{{108-y} \choose 8}{109 \choose 9}$$ to find variance of any $Y_i$?

I also found that if the variance is known, covariance between $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ $(i\neq j)$ can be computed from the equation $\operatorname{var}(\sum_{i=0}^{10} Y_i) = 0$

Comment: What are the $y_i$'s? Observations? Random variables?

Comment: $y_i$s are non-negative integers that satisfy the equation

Comment: I think i could not express the problem well. $y_i$s are the integer non-negative random variables that will satisfy the equation. Definitely $y_i =10$ is not the only solution. And I want to find the variance between all the values $y_i$ can take. I think I should mention that each solution of this equation is equally likely. Does it get clear then?

Comment: Where you have $f_{y_i}(y),$ you need $f_{Y_i}(y).$ Inattentiveness to the distinction between $Y_i$ and $y_i$ can lead to confusion or to inability to do some things, starting with making it impossible to understand $\Pr(Y_i=y_i). \qquad$

Comment: $$
\begin{align} 0 & = \operatorname{var}(100) = \operatorname{var}(Y_1 + \cdots + Y_{10}) = \sum_i \operatorname{var}(Y_i) + 2\sum_{i,j\,:\, i\,<\,j} \operatorname{cov} (Y_i,Y_j) \\ \\ & = 10\v(Y_1) + 2\cdot45\operatorname{cov}(Y_1,Y_2), \\ \\ \end{align}
$$

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to compute the sum by hand, but it is a finite sum, so brute-force yields
$$
\sum_{y=0}^{100} y^2\frac{\binom{108-y}{8}}{\binom{109}9} = 190.
$$
Hence, 
$$
\mathsf{Var}(Y_i) = 190 - 10^2 = 90.
$$